# How to combine two datatable together c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatables. One is a superset of another. Both have one column StageID common. I need to merge these two tables together so that the subset datatables data gets stored in the correct row of superset table.

This is what i did to join the data after retrieving the superset data in JoinTable and subset data in DTMaterialProperties table

```
foreach (DataColumn dcMaterialProp in dtMaterialProperties.Columns) 
{
   if (dcMaterialProp.ColumnName != "StageId" &&  
      JoinDataTable.Columns.Contains(dcMaterialProp.ColumnName))
   {
      JoinDataTable.Rows[rowCount][dcMaterialProp.ColumnName] = 
         dtMaterialProperties.Rows[0][dcMaterialProp.ColumnName];
   }
}
```

But this was not efficient as it takes a lot of time in looping through. 
Please Help me in finding a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LINQ, an easy way would be to use the `Join` extension method.

See [Join Method-Based Query Syntax Examples (LINQ to DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669071.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to LINQ to DataSet

...you can check out this link from MSDN on how to implement a DataSet JOIN Helper Class.

[HOW TO: Implement a DataSet JOIN helper class is Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

What you are really looking for seems to be a relationship.  If you add both datatables to the same dataset, you can define the relationship.  See [Define a relationship between two tables in a DataSet in VB .NET](http://vb-helper.com/howto_net_datagrid_relations.html)

Then, all you have to do is `parentRow.GetChildRows()` to get the associated child rows.